# ¿Como mostrar números redondeados con DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un problema ya que necesito mostrar solo los miles en una tabla (datatables js)
tengo que mostrar solo los 'miles'.

Por ejemplo en el primer numero seria 5 , en el segundo 73.
Quisiera saber como los podría recorrer utilizando datatables

[image]

Para recorrer los decimales utilice esto :  `var FormatDatos = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display;`

Este es Mi codigo para generar toda la tabla:

```
`function AsignaTablaTotalCostoVenta(dg) {
    return $('#' + dg).DataTable({
        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
            };
            var Total = api
                .column(1)
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);
            var Total2 = api
                .column(3)
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);
 
            var FormatDatos = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display;

            TotalCostosFooter1 = Total;
            TotalCostosFooter2 = Total2;
            //$(api.column().footer()).html ('Total') 
            $(api.column(3).footer()).html(FormatDatos(Total2));
            $(api.column(1).footer()).html(FormatDatos(Total));


            var TotalUtilidadBrutaFooter1 = (TotalCostosFooter1 + TotalIngresosFooter1);
            var TotalUtilidadBrutaFooter2 = (TotalCostosFooter2 + TotalIngresosFooter2);
            this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][1].cell.innerHTML = FormatDatos(TotalUtilidadBrutaFooter1);
            this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][3].cell.innerHTML = FormatDatos(TotalUtilidadBrutaFooter2);



        },
        responsive:true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        scrollX: false,
        "ordering": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        fixedColumns: true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'Clasificación', width: '5%',
            }

            ,
            {
                data: 'FECHA', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%',
                render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, ''),
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    if (sData < 0) {
                        $(nTd).css('color', 'red')
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                data: '', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%',
            },
            {
                data: 'Fecha2', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%',
                render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, ''),
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    if (sData < 0) {
                        $(nTd).css('color', 'red')
                    }
                }
            },
            { data:'', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%' },
            {
                data:'', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%'
            },

            {
                data:'', "sClass": "alinear", width: '5%'
            },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            //{
            //    targets:[0],render:Clasificación
            //},
           {
                targets: [2], render: TotalCostoVentaPrimerPorcentaje
            },
            { targets: [4], render: TotalCostoVentaSegundoPorcentaje },
            { targets: [5], render: TotalCostoVentaDiferencia },
            {

                targets: [6], render: TotalCostoVentaVariacionPorcentaje
            }
        ],
    })


}`
```

Tabla Completa :
[image]

Funciones render :

```
`function TotalCostoVentaPrimerPorcentaje(data,type,row,meta,adt) {
    var table = $("#tblTotalCostoVentas").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();
    var Porcentaje = (row.FECHA / Total) * 100
    var PorcentajeEntero = Math.round(Porcentaje)

    if (isNaN(PorcentajeEntero)) {
        return 0 + '%'
    }
    else {
        return PorcentajeEntero + '%'
    }

}

function TotalCostoVentaSegundoPorcentaje(data,type,row,meta,adt) {
    var table = $("#tblTotalCostoVentas").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();
    var Porcentaje = (row.Fecha2 / TotalEstado) * 100
    var PorcentajeEntero = Math.round(Porcentaje)

    if (isNaN(PorcentajeEntero)) {
        return 0 + '%'
    } else {
        return PorcentajeEntero + '%'
    }
    
}

function TotalCostoVentaDiferencia(data,type,row,meta,adt) {
    var table = $("#tblTotalCostoVentas").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();
    var Resultado = row.FECHA - row.Fecha2
    var ResultadoEntero = Math.round(Resultado);

    var ResultadoRenderNumber = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display(ResultadoEntero)

    return ResultadoRenderNumber
}

function TotalCostoVentaVariacionPorcentaje(data,type,row,meta,adt) {
    var table = $("#tblTotalCostoVentas").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();
    var FechaEntero = Math.round(row.FECHA);
    var FechaEntero2 = Math.round(row.Fecha2);
    var resta = FechaEntero - FechaEntero2;
    // var RestaAbs = Math.abs(resta)
    if (FechaEntero <= 0) {
        var Division = FechaEntero2 / FechaEntero2;
        var multiplicacion = Division * 100;
        var MultiplicacionEntero = Math.round(multiplicacion);
        if (isNaN(multiplicacion)) {
            return 0 + '%'
        }
        else {
            return MultiplicacionEntero + '%';

        }
    }
    else {
        var Division = resta / FechaEntero;
        var multiplicacion = Division * 100;
        var MultiplicacionEntero = Math.round(multiplicacion);
    }
    return MultiplicacionEntero + '%';
    
}
`
```

De antemano Muchas Gracias

Comment: No se tiene claro que es lo que quieres. Deseas mostrar solo los número mayores a mil? o recorrerlos como una especia de scrapping?

Comment: Hola, Si ,lo que quiero es No mostrar los números que están después de el coma  ','  Por ejemplo  : 5,523 y lo que quiero es mostrar 5.

Comment: El título de la pregunta sería más bien algo así como _mostrar números redondeados con DataTables_. A no ser que tus comas sean separadores de miles...

Comment: Si ,son Separadores de miles . pero necesito quitarlos para que solo sean un numero  y no mostrar la (,) ejemplo:  5,523 (Cinco Mil Quinientos Veintitrés) y solo quiero mostrar 5 (Cinco Mil)

Comment: @Marcos ya lo actualice

Comment: @JoseLuisDeLaCruzMorales, ¿cual sería la columna? Veo que en varias tenes configuradas funciones `render`, ¿podrías incluir la función en la pregunta?

Comment: @Marcos lo de las columnas render son para sacar Diferencias y porcentajes lo de la imagen es de la columna  `FECHA`

Comment: Como quiera ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Muchas Gracias  @Marcos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías crear una función para formatear, dependiendo el *"tipo de evento"*, el valor.

#### Ejemplo:

```
{
  data: 'FECHA',
  sClass: "alinear",
  width: '5%',
  render: function(data, type) {
     if (type != 'display') return data;
     // Dividimos en 1000, redondeamos para abajo y agregamos la letra 'k'
     // Ejemlo: 5632 => 5k
     return Math.floor(data / 1000) + 'k';
  },
  fnCreatedCell: function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
    if (sData < 0) {
      $(nTd).css('color', 'red')
    }
  }
}
```

---

Referencias:

- [DataTable > column.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Types)

Comment: Muchas Gracias es lo que estaba buscando!